# Airflow run dataproc job with code that sits in git repository

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pyspark, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-composer

I'm looking at the [documentation of the DataProcPySparkOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/dataproc_operator/index.html#airflow.contrib.operators.dataproc_operator.DataProcPySparkOperator) to understand where to send the code file for the pyspark job and the dependencies files (pyfiles). As I understand I should use the "main" and "pyfiles" arguments.
But it's not clear where these files should exist. Can I give a link to git and they will be taken from there, or should I use Google cloud storage (in my case I'm on Google cloud)?
Or should I handle the copy of the files by myself and then provide a link to the master storage?

Comment: Are you using the self managed airflow or cloud composer?

Comment: @psychoCoder I'm using a self-managed but I think the answer should be the same for self-managed and for Composer, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass it in `main`. It can be a local python file or a file on GCS, both are supported. In the case where the file is local, Airflow uploads it to GCS and passed that path to the Dataproc API.